# How to catch cURL errors in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am using [PHP `curl` functions](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) to post data to the web server from my local machine. My code is as follows:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($c);
if (curl_exec($c) === false) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
curl_close($c);
```

Unfortunately I am not able to catch any errors like 404, 500 or network failure. So how will I get to know that data was not posted to or retrieved from the remote?

Answer (score 376, accepted):

You can use the `curl_error()` function to detect if there was some error. For example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $your_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); // Required for HTTP error codes to be reported via our call to curl_error($ch)
//...
curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($error_msg)) {
    // TODO - Handle cURL error accordingly
}
```

[See the description of libcurl error codes here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

[See the description of PHP curl_errno() function here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)

[See the description of PHP curl_error() function here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: @Sarfraz If you don't get any response,meaning the `curl_exec()` return false, does the `curl_error()` return any message?

Comment: it will not be able to catch HTTP error codes. To fix it use the following option `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);`

Comment: "You can use the `curl_error()` function". Proceeds to use `curl_errno()` in the example. :)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That is terrible advice. Not only is it debatable if a 404 is "an error", `curl_exec()` will also **not return the body anymore** if you enable `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR`.

Comment: @AndreKR, It doesn't make sense for me: for the **10**th year period not only a comment - the whole language or its standard library could become outdated.

Answer (score 42):

If `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` is `false`, http errors will not trigger `curl` errors.

```
<?php
if (@$_GET['curl']=="yes") {
  header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
} else {
  $ch=curl_init($url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?curl=yes");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
  $response=curl_exec($ch);
  $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  $curl_errno= curl_errno($ch);
  if ($http_status==503)
    echo "HTTP Status == 503 <br/>";
  echo "Curl Errno returned $curl_errno <br/>";
}
```

Comment: hello new user... it would be nicer to reference the poster's original code and how you would change it.  it makes it easier to digest the answer.  thanks for answering!

Comment: Do you men FAILONERROR?

Comment: Slebetman, you're right.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 23):

you can generate curl error after its execution

```
$url = 'http://example.com';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

and here are curl error code

> if someone need more information about curl errors

```
<?php

    $error_codes=array(
    [1] => 'CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL',
    [2] => 'CURLE_FAILED_INIT',
    [3] => 'CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT',
    [4] => 'CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT_USER',
    [5] => 'CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_PROXY',
    [6] => 'CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST',
    [7] => 'CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT',
    [8] => 'CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_SERVER_REPLY',
    [9] => 'CURLE_REMOTE_ACCESS_DENIED',
    [11] => 'CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_PASS_REPLY',
    [13] => 'CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_PASV_REPLY',
    [14]=>'CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_227_FORMAT',
    [15] => 'CURLE_FTP_CANT_GET_HOST',
    [17] => 'CURLE_FTP_COULDNT_SET_TYPE',
    [18] => 'CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE',
    [19] => 'CURLE_FTP_COULDNT_RETR_FILE',
    [21] => 'CURLE_QUOTE_ERROR',
    [22] => 'CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR',
    [23] => 'CURLE_WRITE_ERROR',
    [25] => 'CURLE_UPLOAD_FAILED',
    [26] => 'CURLE_READ_ERROR',
    [27] => 'CURLE_OUT_OF_MEMORY',
    [28] => 'CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT',
    [30] => 'CURLE_FTP_PORT_FAILED',
    [31] => 'CURLE_FTP_COULDNT_USE_REST',
    [33] => 'CURLE_RANGE_ERROR',
    [34] => 'CURLE_HTTP_POST_ERROR',
    [35] => 'CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR',
    [36] => 'CURLE_BAD_DOWNLOAD_RESUME',
    [37] => 'CURLE_FILE_COULDNT_READ_FILE',
    [38] => 'CURLE_LDAP_CANNOT_BIND',
    [39] => 'CURLE_LDAP_SEARCH_FAILED',
    [41] => 'CURLE_FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND',
    [42] => 'CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK',
    [43] => 'CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT',
    [45] => 'CURLE_INTERFACE_FAILED',
    [47] => 'CURLE_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS',
    [48] => 'CURLE_UNKNOWN_TELNET_OPTION',
    [49] => 'CURLE_TELNET_OPTION_SYNTAX',
    [51] => 'CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION',
    [52] => 'CURLE_GOT_NOTHING',
    [53] => 'CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_NOTFOUND',
    [54] => 'CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_SETFAILED',
    [55] => 'CURLE_SEND_ERROR',
    [56] => 'CURLE_RECV_ERROR',
    [58] => 'CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM',
    [59] => 'CURLE_SSL_CIPHER',
    [60] => 'CURLE_SSL_CACERT',
    [61] => 'CURLE_BAD_CONTENT_ENCODING',
    [62] => 'CURLE_LDAP_INVALID_URL',
    [63] => 'CURLE_FILESIZE_EXCEEDED',
    [64] => 'CURLE_USE_SSL_FAILED',
    [65] => 'CURLE_SEND_FAIL_REWIND',
    [66] => 'CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_INITFAILED',
    [67] => 'CURLE_LOGIN_DENIED',
    [68] => 'CURLE_TFTP_NOTFOUND',
    [69] => 'CURLE_TFTP_PERM',
    [70] => 'CURLE_REMOTE_DISK_FULL',
    [71] => 'CURLE_TFTP_ILLEGAL',
    [72] => 'CURLE_TFTP_UNKNOWNID',
    [73] => 'CURLE_REMOTE_FILE_EXISTS',
    [74] => 'CURLE_TFTP_NOSUCHUSER',
    [75] => 'CURLE_CONV_FAILED',
    [76] => 'CURLE_CONV_REQD',
    [77] => 'CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE',
    [78] => 'CURLE_REMOTE_FILE_NOT_FOUND',
    [79] => 'CURLE_SSH',
    [80] => 'CURLE_SSL_SHUTDOWN_FAILED',
    [81] => 'CURLE_AGAIN',
    [82] => 'CURLE_SSL_CRL_BADFILE',
    [83] => 'CURLE_SSL_ISSUER_ERROR',
    [84] => 'CURLE_FTP_PRET_FAILED',
    [84] => 'CURLE_FTP_PRET_FAILED',
    [85] => 'CURLE_RTSP_CSEQ_ERROR',
    [86] => 'CURLE_RTSP_SESSION_ERROR',
    [87] => 'CURLE_FTP_BAD_FILE_LIST',
    [88] => 'CURLE_CHUNK_FAILED');

    ?>
```

Answer (score 23):

Since you are interested in catching network related errors and HTTP errors, the following provides a better approach:

```
function curl_error_test($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $responseBody = curl_exec($ch);
    /*
     * if curl_exec failed then
     * $responseBody is false
     * curl_errno() returns non-zero number
     * curl_error() returns non-empty string
     * which one to use is up too you
     */
    if ($responseBody === false) {
        return "CURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }

    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    /*
     * 4xx status codes are client errors
     * 5xx status codes are server errors
     */
    if ($responseCode >= 400) {
        return "HTTP Error: " . $responseCode;
    }

    return "No CURL or HTTP Error";
}
```

Tests:

```
curl_error_test("http://expamle.com");          // CURL Error: Could not resolve host: expamle.com
curl_error_test("http://example.com/whatever"); // HTTP Error: 404
curl_error_test("http://example.com");          // No CURL or HTTP Error
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    $responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);
    $result=array();
    $result['httpCode']=$httpCode;
    $result['body']=json_decode($body);
    $result['responseInfo']=$responseInfo;
    print_r($httpCode); 
     print_r($result['body']); exit;
    curl_close($ch);
    if($httpCode == 403)
    {
        print_r("Access denied");
        exit;
    }   
    else
     {
         //catch more errors 
     }
```

Comment: Hey Sunil, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you give some explanation what your code does and how it helps to catch the errors described by Harish?

Comment: still waiting (lol) .. better to head to php.net curl docs and sort out the unknown