# How to try - catch if any error occurs?

Tags: php, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to catch curl errors in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php)

I have got some lines of code:

```
<?php
try {
    $my_curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($my_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $one_url); 
    curl_setopt($my_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($my_curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $datum = curl_exec($my_curl);
    curl_close($my_curl);

    $my_image = imagecreatefromstring($datum);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}       
?>
```

When running in real environment, some sites which contain images (as `$one_url`) cannot access or died or ... cause one/ or many of lines of code turn into errors.

How can I try - catch if any statement cannot be done successfully? In other words, I like try - catch works like... switch - case (not if else).

Any advice will be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`curl_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php):

```
$datum = curl_exec($my_curl);
if($datum === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you throw an Exception when false is returned?
i.e.

```
if ($curlResp === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception(); 
}
```

Check [**this**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)
***Return Values***

Returns TRUE on success or `FALSE` on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, it will return the result on success, `FALSE` on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(curl_errno($my_curl))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($my_curl);
}
```