# Unable to load and store XML string

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm attempting to read an XML feed and store the contents in a file on my server. The script that does this is called via AJAX on page load and only runs if it has been at least 3 minutes since the last update.

The code below seemed to be working fine previously, but now I'm getting this: "Fatal error: Call to a member function asXml() on a non-object"

The server on which the XML feed is hosted was recently "reset". I noticed this issue on the day that happened, however, the feed is still accessible and appears fine.

```
if (get_option('last_showtime_check') < (time() - (5 * 60))) {

  update_option('last_showtime_check', time());

  $url = "http://somedomain.com/showtimes.xml";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

  echo var_dump($ch); // Returns "resource (261) of type (curl)"

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

  echo var_dump($xml); // Returns "bool(false)"

  $xml->asXml('showtimes-test.xml');

}
```

Comment: `Returns "bool(false)"` Well, thats the problem! The http request is failing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php

Comment: Yea, no idea why it would be though! http://somedomain.com/showtimes.xml is accessible...

Comment: The SO question i linked shows how you can access curl errors - that should help you track down the cause.

Comment: Thanks! Got a "couldn't connect to host" error. Checking in with those in charge of the remote server to see if there's some sort of restriction in place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to download the XML file from a remote server and save it locally, you can do this rather simply like so:

```
if (get_option('last_showtime_check') < (time() - (5 * 60))) {
    file_put_contents('showtimes-test.xml',
        file_get_contents('http://somedomain.com/showtimes.xml'));
}
```

P.s. `echo var_dump($xml); // Returns "bool(false)"` - check your file url - does it exists?

---

**Update**

It is possible, the server you are trying to load the XML file from only serves an XML file, if the correct `Accept` header is set. It is likely that the browser is automatically setting it based on the file ext. Try this 2nd method:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Accept: application/xml'
    )
));
file_put_contents('showtimes-test.xml',
    file_get_contents('http://somedomain.com/showtimes.xml', false, $context));
```

Comment: Much simpler. I'm getting a blank document in showtimes-test.xml. When I enter the file URL into my browser, it's accessible and shows me the XML tree. Maybe checking the curl errors as @Steve suggested will give me some more insight.

Comment: see if updated answer helps. Try loading the the xml url in Chrome and monitor network using the dev tools to see what headers are sent and what headers are in the response. Might give you a clue.