# Paypal IPN Verified but not running my INSERT

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have used the example from Paypal's website and just added my INSERT query to it. I have even used a generic Name to insert to make sure it was not a problem with my code. The I have a file named ipn.log but it does not update and the database also does not update.If I go to my listener page it also does not throw any errors. Using Paypal's IPN simulator it returns VERIFIED.

```html
<?php
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
 $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
 if (count($keyval) == 2)
  $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
 $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
 if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
 } else {
  $value = urlencode($value);
 }
 $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
 $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
 $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
 return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
 {
 if(DEBUG == true) { 
  error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
 }
 curl_close($ch);
 exit;
} else {
  // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
  if(DEBUG == true) {
   error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
   error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
  }
  curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
 // check whether the payment_status is Completed
 // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
 // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
 // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
 // process payment and mark item as paid.
 // assign posted variables to local variables
 //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
 //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
 //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
 //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
 //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
 //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
 //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
 $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    //my code
    if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db('database', $link)) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
    }

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO test1 '.
      '(Name) '.
      'VALUES ("Duane")';
    mysql_query($sql, $link);

    mysql_close();
    //my code
 
 if(DEBUG == true) {
  error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
 }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
 // log for manual investigation
 // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
 if(DEBUG == true) {
  error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run some tests so that you can see what PHP errors, MySQL, etc. might be happening when the code runs.  Follow the steps in [this article on testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and you should be able to find your problem.

If it looks like it's stopping after curl is executed then there must be some sort of an error happening there.  You'll need to catch the cURL error and echo that out or log it accordingly.

Here is [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php) with more details on that.

Comment: I have added an echo to various parts of the code and it looks like the code just stops running after curl is complete.

Comment: Being able to see what error curl was giving was crucial. I just had path incorrect for the cacert.pem thank you