# PayPal error when customers check out

Tags: paypal, payment

my website is www.a1mcganns.co.uk

I am having issues with customers completing payment when using PayPal.

They get this error message

1. **PayPal response:**
2. ->
3. Making new connection to 'api-3t.paypal.com/nvp'
4. Connect with CURL method successful
5. **Sending this params:**
6. METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=106&PWD=L2JP7EMP7JR32JCP&USER=sales_api1.a1mcganns.co.uk&SIGNATURE=AENSDlLTRY8C54MMOG29Y0inxhFWAgY-7uEg9VqBu-bS11n1QZx2H3Nv&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.a1mcganns.co.uk%2Fgb%2Forder%3Fpaypal_ec_canceled%3D1%26&RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.a1mcganns.co.uk%2Fmodules%2Fpaypal%2Fexpress_checkout%2Fpayment.php&NOSHIPPING=1&BUTTONSOURCE=PRESTASHOP_EC&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=1733&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Cycliq+Fly+12+Front+1080p+Camera+and+400+lumen+Bike+Light+%28Includes+16GB+SD+Card%29&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Inludes+16GB+SD+Card...&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=229.99&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=229.99&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=229.99&ADDROVERRIDE=1&EMAIL=phil%40wilkinson3.fsworld.co.uk&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=p+Wilkinson&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=%2B447595914321&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=63&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=Northampton+Lane+North&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=Northampton&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=GB&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=NN3+7QY&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Login&USER=sales_api1.a1mcganns.co.uk&PWD=L2JP7EMP7JR32JCP&SIGNATURE=AENSDlLTRY8C54MMOG29Y0inxhFWAgY-7uEg9VqBu-bS11n1QZx2H3Nv
7. Send with CURL method failed ! Error: Couldn't resolve host 'api-3t.paypal.com'
8. Connect failed with fsockopen method

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to fix the problem

Many thanks

Regards
Phil

Comment: Couldn't resolve host 'api-3t.paypal.com' might be a start. Check DNS/hosts config

Answer (score 0):

[Check the curl error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php) to see exactly what's happening.  My guess is that you'll get something along the lines of "ssl handshake failure".

If that's the case you need to review [this post about POODLE](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/).

The problem basically comes down to the server software stack being out of date.  Specifically, from the POODLE post...

> As of 01.19.2016 PayPal now supports only TLS 1.2 on the sandbox (and in June the same will apply to production systems).
>
> If you want to use TLS 1.2 you’ll need to upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.1 as a minimum, and then you’ll be able to set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 6 (TLS 1.2).
>
> If you want TLS 1.2 to be used automatically during SSL requests, you’ll also need to upgrade to PHP 5.5.19+ (this is the ideal solution but many projects are still on older PHP versions).