# curl request resource id# 12 ERROR

Tags: php, curl

My curl request is..

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE,$proxy);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PORT, '8888');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
pr($ch);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Error Resource id #12
i am trying to fetch data from amazon and have a list of ip address, and port number.
sending request from diff port number preventing blocking from amazon...

Comment: What's the values of $url and $proxy? What is the output of curl_error()?

Comment: $URL="https://www.amazon.com/s/?page=1&field-keywords=books+&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3A=books&lo=strips&low-price=10&high-price=20000&ref=s9_acss_bw_en_BGG15eve_d_1_2?_encoding=UTF8&node=2&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-top-3&pf_rd_r=MP3N7TX4MQHGDQFDHH4V&pf_rd_r=MP3N7TX4MQHGDQFDHH4V&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=593f03ec-42c4-42a6-9137-4fbc35330991&pf_rd_p=593f03ec-42c4-42a6-9137-4fbc35330991&pf_rd_i=283155"

Comment: and proxy is 108.62.150.134
tell me whats the solution??

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your curl client is getting some response from server that it can not understand, *Error#12* means: **CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_USER_REPLY**

here is the PHP Manual link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php

and description of error: http://web.mit.edu/jhawk/mnt/ss.b/curl-7.10.5/docs/libcurl/libcurl-errors.html

You can use curl_error to capture the error [How to catch curl errors in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php)

Other thing to consider here is your proxy, is it allowed to access the host and port you are trying to access and you access the host without proxy?

Comment: any solution?? need your help??

Comment: did you try connecting to host directly? is there any IP restriction on host you are trying to connect ?

Comment: I'm scraping amazon, and when first did scraping i did't know that more than one requests in second block your IP address,
in my case request more than 20 times and amazon block my IP address and show Robot Check, impossible to  skip it

Comment: trying adding  a delay, if you are making frequent hits, they'll block your IP for sure

Comment: have a look at this article, it's old, but still relevant : http://ghostproxies.com/blog/2015/09/7-things-to-know-before-scraping-amazon-product-results/

Comment: Things are now out of control, had enough of it, now how to skip Robot Check, read the article already, but need solution... Im searching to solve this problem for last 12 hours but did't fine any solution... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132501/discussion-between-muhammad-awais-zulifqar-and-ravish).

Answer (score 2):

```
CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_SERVER_REPLY (8)
```

The server sent data libcurl couldn't parse. This error code is used for more than just FTP and is aliased as `CURLE_WEIRD_SERVER_REPLY` since 7.51.0.

```
CURLE_REMOTE_ACCESS_DENIED (9)
```

We were denied access to the resource given in the URL. For FTP, this occurs while trying to change to the remote directory.

```
CURLE_FTP_ACCEPT_FAILED (10)
```

While waiting for the server to connect back when an active FTP session is used, an error code was sent over the control connection or similar.

```
CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_PASS_REPLY (11)
```

After having sent the FTP password to the server, libcurl expects a proper reply. This error code indicates that an unexpected code was returned.

```
CURLE_FTP_ACCEPT_TIMEOUT (12)
```

During an active FTP session while waiting for the server to connect, the `CURLOPT_ACCEPTTIMEOUT_MS` (or the internal default) timeout expired.

for more details 
[enter link description here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Answer (score 1):

CURLE_FTP_ACCEPT_TIMEOUT (12)

During an active FTP session while waiting for the server to connect, the CURLOPT_ACCEPTTIMEOUT_MS (or the internal default) timeout expired.