# php curl fetch content from website is not working

Tags: php, curl

My OS window 7 using Xampp server.
In my localhost i got output but using https protocols means i am getting empty response. May I need to update any thing in my below code to get website content.

```
print_r(curl_version());
```

**Output**

```
    Array
(
    [version_number] => 470785
    [age] => 3
    [features] => 266141
    [ssl_version_number] => 0
    [version] => 7.47.1
    [host] => i386-pc-win32
    [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/1.0.2d
    [libz_version] => 1.2.7.3
    [protocols] => Array
        (
            [0] => dict
            [1] => file
            [2] => ftp
            [3] => ftps
            [4] => gopher
            [5] => http
            [6] => https
            [7] => imap
            [8] => imaps
            [9] => ldap
            [10] => pop3
            [11] => pop3s
            [12] => rtsp
            [13] => scp
            [14] => sftp
            [15] => smtp
            [16] => smtps
            [17] => telnet
            [18] => tftp
        )

)
```

My curl program:

```
// is cURL installed yet?
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}

// OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/sites/AAA/default.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://example.com/sites/AAA/default.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla15-1.0");
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 8089);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch); print_r( $output);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Add this and then see. 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Answer (score 0):

To verify host or peer certificate you need to specify alternate certificates with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.

When the verify value is 1, curl_easy_setopt will return an error and the option value will not be changed. It was previously (in 7.28.0 and earlier) a debug option of some sorts, but it is no longer supported due to frequently leading to programmer mistakes. Future versions will stop returning an error for 1 and just treat 1 and 2 the same.

When the verify value is 0, the connection succeeds regardless of the names in the certificate. Use that ability with caution!

The default value for this option is 2.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Added two lines but getting same empty response. Not able to fetch content. Any other possiblity is there?

Comment: Yes, print the errors and show me. You can show error using this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php

Comment: Then this code curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); should be working. have you changed $ch to your own variable? show your code after adding these two lines.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/sites/AAA/default.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://example.com/sites/AAA/default.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch); print_r( $output);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}else{
 echo "success";
}
curl_close($ch);
This code i am getting success message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143273/discussion-between-balaguru-murugan-and-davinder-kumar).