# Twilio not working with alphanumeric sender id using curl php

Tags: php, curl, twilio-api

I need to send sms with alphanumeric sender id with curl php..!! i have enabled alpha numeric sender id the console... but i was not able to send the sms with sender id here below is my code.. if i send with the from phone number sms working fine..!! but i need to mask my number as alphanumeric senderid..if i use alphanumeric sender id sms not sending and displays no error..

```
   $id = "******"; 
    $token ="******";  
    $url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$id/SMS/Messages";
    $from = "AGNAFAF"; 
    $to = "+91***";
    //$to=$to;
    $body = "TEST";
    $data = array (
        'From' => $from,    
        'To' => $to,
        'Body' => $body
    );
    $post = $data;
    $x = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token");
    curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $y = curl_exec($x);
    curl_close($x);
    return $out = explode('|', $y);
echo $out;
```

Comment: What does "unable to" mean? What error are you given?

Comment: its not showing any error message..!!do i want to add any parameter in this code...

Comment: You should check whether there are any errors in cURL. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php#answer-3987037).

Comment: error message - The 'From' number AGNAFAF is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID.https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21212400

Answer (score 0):

Alphanumeric Sender ID feature is only available when sending messages to supported countries. Some countries require pre-registered alpha sender IDs and they can only be used to send transactional messages.

You can find supported Country list [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID)

Comment: The USA is one of the countries that does not support alphaSender. I know the OP references another country but this can catch a lot of people (like me).

Answer (score 0):

this error is due to the url... twilio have provided updated json url
$url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$id/SMS/Messages";
instead of 
$url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$id/Messages.json";

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? Just changing what you suggested does not work to me.

Comment: That just changes the response format to xml instead of JSON