# php to post json data into api

Tags: php, json, api

php form submit converted the JSON formate the URL API to post that data but data will not post API key also passed but not working

```
   $values->email = $_POST['email'];
   $values->password = $_POST['password'];
   $values->phone = $_POST['phoneno'];
   $values->owner_id = $_POST['operator_id'];
   $values->bank_name = $_POST['bankname'];
   $values->ifsc_code = $_POST['ifsc'];
   $values->last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
   $values->created_by = 'mobiadmin';
   $values->first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
   $values->account_type = $_POST['accounttype'];
   $values->schema = $_POST['schema'];
   $values->merchant_meta = array("id"=> null);
   $values->merchant_name = $_POST['merchantname'];
   $values->account_number = $_POST['accountno'];
   $values->acc_holder_name = $_POST['accountholder'];
   $array = array("records"=>array($values));
   $json_formate = json_encode($array);

   $ch = curl_init('api');                             
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_formate);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',
                 'x-api-key:aMqwyQJdA1aqH5GkpG5NR78UyswcHhkEaMZCfrC8',                                                          
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_formate))                                                                       
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: So where is this API located?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow");` add this line with your api url

Comment: $ch = curl_init('api');

Comment: not working @RasaMohameda

Comment: @Raghav It should be `$ch = curl_init($api);`  `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$api);` before this you have to set `$api=your URL here;` so what is your `$api=?`

Comment: down but not work I add the heard API key also not work

Comment: @Raghav You can use the `curl_error()` function to detect if there was some error `if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
} ` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194978/discussion-between-raghav-and-rasa-mohamed).

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an very simple example how I set up my API and call it from mobile apps or where you would like to fetch from. I've put in some comments and hope this will give you some clarification or examples to further in your project.

**API**

```
<?php
// this API just fetch articels from a specific URL and view them as a list
// with numbers between from and to
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com", false); // allowed addresses
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com", false); // allowed addresses
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET POST"); // choose GET|POST
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // choose type

$file = "classes/Articles.php";

$limit_from = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "limit_from", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$limit_to = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "limit_to", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$articles = new \common\controller\Articles(BASE);
$list = $articles->getArticles((isset($limit_from)) ? $limit_from : 0, (isset($limit_to)) ? $limit_to : 10);
echo json_encode($list);
```

**Fetch api with cURL from PHP page.**
*Could be a single page, function or a method*

```
// create a new cURL resource
// use this option curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "address"); or put address as
// an parameter in curl_init(example address)
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/api/public/article/name/example-name");

// Example of sending POST|GET data through cURL
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('postvar1' =>'value1')));

// Here you can add you API key choose Authorization|x-api-key
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization: example-key'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
```

Though this is an GET API you could easley turn it into a POST API.

Read more about https://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: where I pass x-api-key in this method

Comment: @Raghav added API key into cURL options. Should work