# PHP Curl Posting Code that i made is not working

Tags: php, curl

I am using post method and sql query to send sms. So, I am just trying to get this link formet

http://example.com/smsapi/non-masking?api_key=$2y$10$mtW.yfKj18i2mTPe/0iCEuKdCfCGh9zOYYEU9AmnMrJyBb.h7fVcG&smsType=text&mobileNo=(NUMBER)&smsContent=(Message Content)

but my curl code is not working.

```php
    $api_key = "$2y$10$mtW.yfKj18i2mTPe/0iCEuKdCfCGh9zOYYEU9AmnMrJyBb.h7fVcG";
    $numbers = "$row[mailing_no]"; 
    $message = "Dear Guardian, $row[name] has swiped his card right now";
    $type= "text";
    $params = array('api_key'=>'$api_key', 'smsType'=>'$type', 'mobileNo'=>'$number', 'smsContent'=>'$message');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/smsapi/non-masking?".http_build_query($params, "", "&"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "Accept:application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: use this instead of line 5 and check if this solves your problem: `$params = array('api_key' => $api_key, 'smsType' => $type, 'mobileNo' => $numbers, 'smsContent' => $message)`;

Comment: no this is not working still now.

Comment: curl_error($ch) hacve you tried this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php

Comment: print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); You can get the CURL request details using this function.

Answer (score 0):

Just made some improvements to your code, you were using `$number` on `$params`, but the variable was named `$numbers`

```
 $api_key = "$2y$10$mtW.yfKj18i2mTPe/0iCEuKdCfCGh9zOYYEU9AmnMrJyBb.h7fVcG";
    $number = $row[mailing_no]; 
    $message = "Dear Guardian, ". $row[name] . " has swiped his card right now";
    $type= "text";
    $params = array('api_key'=>$api_key, 'smsType'=>$type, 'mobileNo'=>$number, 'smsContent'=>$message);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/smsapi/non-masking?".http_build_query($params, "", "&"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "Accept:application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Please add explanation how your answer solves the issue to improve the quality of answers!

Comment: i have fixed that variable but this not working still now

Comment: this is my full problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58724690/i-want-to-convert-a-post-method-form-to-curl-command