# Get instagram public JSON feed with cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

I want to use cURL to get the JSON response from a public available instagram profile. I'm stuck to the response, because If I try to `var_dump` the data it will result in nothing, a blank string. Is there something wrong in my code?

```
$url = 'https://instagram.com/'.$instance['username'].'/?__a=1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json') );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump( $url );
```

The `$instance` variable is set using a wordpress widget input form and is correct. My problems are only with the curl beahviour.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, make sure the `$instance['username']` is actually set and doesn't contain any whitespace and that the profile is public

Comment: I've tried using `file_get_contents` and it's working, but with curl not. I'm implementing this inside a wordpress widget on the front-end part of the code. I've vardumped the $url variable and it's set when the request is made, but I can't get a response back.

Comment: @kerbholz do you tested it?

Comment: May be worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Yep, tested it, as it is, worked without `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` - but the problem seems to be solved anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script needs a `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` parameter to be set.

```
$url = 'https://instagram.com/'. $instance['username'] .'/?__a=1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json') );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data); // Show the response
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why please?Thanks for the help

Comment: @sisaln, the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` tells the library to follow any Location: ... read more: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html