# How to get Instagram public feed without login PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I want to get public Instagram feed with PHP cURL from "https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1". It shows me the JSON when I type the url manually in the browser but it redirects me to the Instagram login page when I run the code with PHP cURL. Is there a way to fix it with a proxy or cookie in PHP cURL?

My code is:

```
$username = 'kyliejenner';
$url = 'https://instagram.com/'. $username .'/?__a=1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json') );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data); // Show the response
```

I get the code from [Get instagram public JSON feed with cURL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435149/get-instagram-public-json-feed-with-curl-php)

Comment: you could probably use the instagram developper api, but if you do, you will probably have to create an application application in the facebook developper console to get an api key

Comment: Have you tried to set a User-Agent header? I guess Instragram detect that the request does not come from a Browser

Comment: Yes i tried with some but it didn't work. Should I request with session or cookie?

Comment: I have a website and I get more than 20k+ pageviews in a day so I think i'll need many Instagram accounts for too many requests

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Instagram is checking headers and also if a session cookie is included (to be confirmed)
In my project, it works for few days until i get an error 429. After few days it requests now a login before sending the JSON

Here are my headers that worked for few days

```
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Mobile Safari/537.36'
```