# fopen and CURLOPT_FAILONERROR

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to this. How to NOT write to the file if CURLOPT_FAILONERROR is triggered?

```
$token = "123";
$url = "foo.com";
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "wb");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Not sure that is directly possible. You might have to receive the response in a variable first, and then write it to a file yourself, after you checked there were no errors (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that is possible in that way.
I download the origin file first in /tmp and if there isn't error then I move it to whatever you want.

```
$tmpFp = null;
$token = '123';
$url = 'foo.com';
$source = '';
$dest = 'file.txt';
$meta = null;

try {
    // creating tmp file
    $tmpFp = tmpfile();
    $meta = stream_get_meta_data($tmpFp);
    // getting its name
    $source = $meta['uri'];

    if($tmpFp === false){
        throw new Exception('Could not open Temporal File');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $tmpFp);
    curl_exec($ch);
    // download file

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }

    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($tmpFp);

    if($statusCode != 200) {
        // if the file don't exist or some other web error 
        throw new Exception('Status Code: '. $statusCode);
    }

    // copy to dest
    if (!copy($source, $des)) {
        throw new Exception('failed to copy file');
    }

    echo('Download success!');

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

last note, make sure that you have permissions

regards