# Use cURL to fetch XML and JSON data from my API

Tags: java, php, spring-boot, api, crud

I gave myself a project that involves basic CRUD operations with Spring-boot Java as back-end and PHP as front-end. I have my API up and running, I have tested the routes with Postman and I am getting back a response depending on the header I set in postman [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBGOh.png). Here you can also see in my Java backend code I make sure my API can return both XML and JSON.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/cabbage",
        produces = {
                MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        })
public @ResponseBody
Iterable<CabbageFarm> getCabbageData() {
    return cabbageRepo.findAll();
}
```

The problem now for me is consuming the route with cURL in order to store the JSON or XML values I get in an array for further manipulation but when ever I do, I get NULL. Here is my php code.

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = "localhost:8080/cabbage";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: Accept:application/json"));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);

    var_dump($data);
?>
```

In this code above I am attempting to consume JSON hence the

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: Accept:application/json"))

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because you close curl resource too early, try to reverse these lines

```
curl_close($ch); $data = json_decode($result, true);
```

like this

```
$data = json_decode($result, true); curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I tried this and it still returned NULL

Comment: hum, the header seems to be malformated, can you change `array("Content-Type: Accept:application/json")` by this `array("Content-Type: application/json")`.

If you look at php docs https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php they preconize like this.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work

Comment: Take a look here, you need to get the real errors to resolve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php