# How do I send POST request to REST API properly through cURL?

Tags: php, rest

I am trying fetch the access token by exchanging the code received from the URL and I have already configured the redirect uri and other configurations. The following is my callback.php:

```php
$code = $_GET["code"];
$client_id = "";//actual client id
$client_secret = ""//actual client secret;
$redirect_uri = "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2Fwebex_integration_test%2Fcallback.php";
$postRequest = array(
          "client_id" => ""//actual client id,
          "client_secret" => ""//actual client secret,
          "code" => $_GET["code"],
          "redirect_uri" => "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2Fwebex_integration_test%2Fcallback.php",
          "code_verifier" => "abc"
        );
$cURLConnection = curl_init("https://api.webex.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&code=$code&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&code_verifier=abc");
      curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postRequest);
      curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                          'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                          'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                          ));
$apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);
$jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($apiResponse);
print_r($jsonArrayResponse);
```

The above request results in a blank page. I am expecting the access token.

Comment: Do you have any errors (may be in the log file or you can enable them on the specific page)?  Also check if there are any [curl errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php).

Comment: I am not receiving any status code, I have tested this request in POSTMAN and it works fine, but when I try through php its resulting in a blank page

Comment: A blank page could mean an error, it could mean no content.  Have you tried adding an `echo` at the bottom of the code to see if it will at least get to the end of the script?

Comment: I just tried adding a print statement at the end of the script and its printing.

Comment: Try displaying the curl response - `echo $apiResponse;` as it could be that it's not JSON.

Comment: "Incorrect request parameters",Yes, that was the problem, I was expecting it be a JSON response. I will check the parameters once again but when I used the same parameters in POSTMAN it responded with a 200 status code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this class for PHP composer and don't waste the time

https://github.com/MoovFun/Xo-Curl