# How can I make errors that I may encounter in php curl with try / catch?

Tags: php, curl, request, try-catch

I wanted to circumvent the errors I might encounter in php curl with try / catch, but the cath part does not work, where is the problem ??

```
<?php
    try {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $ch = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://example.com/api?username=".$username."&password=".$pass);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        
        $json = json_decode($server_output, true);
        
        $token = $json["session"]["sessionId"];
        echo $token;
        curl_close ($ch);
        
        
    }
    
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Error";
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: cURL itself does not _throw_ exceptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch curl errors in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php)

Comment: @CBroe so how can I overcome any possible errors?

Comment: This code does not generate exception, so you need to manage to create custom exception based on your error handling. see updated code below

Comment: @MominIqbal No, if the login information is incorrect, it cannot receive tokens and therefore gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Find below updated snippet to throw an exeption when token is empty...

```
   <?php
    try {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $ch = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://example.com/api?username=".$username."&password=".$pass);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        
        $json = json_decode($server_output, true);
        
        $token = $json["session"]["sessionId"];

        if(empty($token)){
            throw new Exception('Token not found');
        }
        echo $token;
        curl_close ($ch);
        
        
    }
    
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Error";
    }
    
    ?>
```

I have added below line to make sure that your code catch exception when there is no token...

```
if(empty($token)){
   throw new Exception('Token not found');
}
```

Comment: Well after this code I used a different curl, if there is an error in that part, how do I catch it?

Comment: If your curl response will thrown FATAL error then you don't have to do anything. But if your curl request is successful, but unable get any response (response is empty or any other logic that you would like to apply) then you need to manage manually as did in empty token case

Comment: I tried the code you threw, because there is no token value, an error appears in that $ token line.

Comment: what is the value/error in $token variable?

Comment: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login_v15\sonuc.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login_v15\sonuc.php on line 14
Error

Comment: Try this `if (error_reporting()) {
    throw new Exception( $token);
  }` after `$token`  . Whenever $token thrown an error it will catch exception

Comment: This fatal error came on top of it
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login_v15\sonuc.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login_v15\sonuc.php on line 17

Comment: @Bilalİnal "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" indicates there was an issue with decoding the response as json, not an issue with curl. Dump your response (before decoding!) and see what you actually got back.