# Any ideas why this cURL script isn't working

Tags: php, curl

I literally have similar cURL scripts running on other areas of this PHP page, and they work just fine.  But for some reason, this one is different enough to be causing me problems.  No error message, it just doesn't seem to be hitting the endpoint for some reason.  Can you see any reason why this wouldn't work?

```
ob_start();
$destination = "https://www.example.com/record_serial_number.php?serial_number=" . $serial_number . "&employee_name=" . $employee_name . "&scan_purpose=Barcode printed&value=";
$destination = urlencode($destination);

$url = $destination;  
$ch = curl_init();  

// set URL and other appropriate options  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "hidden_username:hidden_password");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Have you checked [`curl_error()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php)

Comment: Well, you've completely messed up your URL with urlencode. `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Frecord_serial_number.php%3F`... you need to use urlencode on your individual variables, not the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `curl_errno()` and `curl_error()` to find out if `curl_exec()` encountered an error.